# Vi like editing operating system wide?

Tags: macos, vi

Is there an extension I can install on Mac OS X that lets me use vi like commands everywhere in the operating system? And if this is not possible, is there a solution that just extends the terminal?

Comment: You may like the `vi` editing mode for the `bash` shell. Issue the command `set -o vi` to enable,  and `set -o emacs` to restore the default. This will not have any impact on other applications, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `bash` shell supports `vi`-like editing for the command line. Enable it with `set -o vi`, and `set -o emacs` to restore the default behavior.

The `vi` mode will enable moded editing of the command-line: the initial state is `insert-mode`, and pressing `Esc` will enter `command-mode`.

The `set` command can be issued from your `~/.bashrc` to take effect in all new shells.

Note this change will only affect the shell in Terminal, `iTerm2`, etc., but will not have any impact on other applications.